# Advanced MySQL Insert with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, insert, sql-insert

I am trying to fill a column in MySQL using a joint table and existing value.

I have two tables -

```
__________________________
|          papers        |   
| paperid | title | year |   
| 1.0.2   | Awed  | 1999 |   
_______________________________________
|           citations                 |
| title | year | paperid | refPaperID |
| othP  | 1999 | 1.3.4.5 | NULL       |
```

I want to fill the citations.refPaperID column in every row with the paper.paperid of the row in papers which has a matching citations.title LIKE papers.title +  citations.year = papers.year.

Comment: Do you want to **insert** new rows in the citations table or do actually want to **update** the current rows in it?

Comment: Update the current rows in citations table So for every row in citations table, the rePaperID value points to the paperid of the paper which has the same title and year as in the citation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE citations SET
citations.refPaperID = (SELECT papers.paperid
                        FROM papers
                        WHERE citations.title = papers.title
                        AND citations.year = papers.year)
```

But for this to work, the `SELECT` query must match and return one single record, which means that the records in your citations table must have unique title+year combination.

**Edit**

MySQL does not have an implementation of `FIRST()` and `LAST()`, so to get the first match, you can use `LIMIT 1` like this:

```
UPDATE citations SET
citations.refPaperID = (SELECT papers.paperid
                        FROM papers
                        WHERE citations.title = papers.title
                        AND citations.year = papers.year
                        LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it use the first record if the subquery finds multiple matches?

Comment: And to only update the row if citations.year and citations.year are not NULL

Comment: @BradStevenson Yes, you can use `LIMIT 1`. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to do this with a `join`:

```
update citations c join
       papers p
       on c.title = p.title and
          c.year = p.year     
    set c.refPaperID = p.paperid;
```